Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0' after deployment
I'm encountering an issue with my .NET Framework 4.6 application after deployment. Locally, everything works fine, but upon deployment, I'm getting the following error:
Exception caught: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

My application is built on .NET Framework 4.6.
In my web.config file, I have the following configuration for System.Net.Http:

<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />


Checked local environment, where everything is functioning correctly.
Confirmed that the System.Net.Http assembly is included in the deployment package.
Reviewed the web.config file to ensure proper configuration.


Why am I encountering this error after deployment, and how can I resolve it?
Is there any additional configuration or steps I should take to ensure compatibility after deployment?

Note: I'm using .NET Framework 4.6, and the version specified in the error message is 4.2.0.0. Could this be a version mismatch issue?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance
